# How solve empty reCAPTCHA token error in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on flutter project and I need to implement reset password functionality with firebase. But when I'm calling the **FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: _emailTextController.text.trim());** I'm getting this message  ***I/FirebaseAuth(15521): Password reset request email@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token*** . And also cannot retrieved the emails thay are not in the databse.

my code:-

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:logginapplication/reusable_widgets/logo_widget.dart';
import '../../reusable_widgets/textFeild_widget.dart';

class ForgotPasswordScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ForgotPasswordScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ForgotPasswordScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<ForgotPasswordScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _emailTextController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _emailTextController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future passwordReset() async {
    print("Password reset inside");
    try{
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ));
      print("Inside try block------------>>");
      await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .sendPasswordResetEmail(
          email: _emailTextController.text.trim());
      Navigator.pop(context);
      showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: Text("Password reset email send to the mentioned email address."),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: const Text("OK")),
          ],
        );
      });
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){
      print("Error-------------->>>");
      print(e);
      showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: Text(e.message.toString()),
        );
      });
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white10,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
        },
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
            Colors.white,
            Colors.black38,
            Colors.black54,
          ], begin: Alignment.topCenter, end: Alignment.bottomCenter)),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  (20), MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1, 20, 0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  logoWidget("assets/images/img_2.png"),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  const Text("FORGOT PASSWORD",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 24,
                      )),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "To change the password please enter the provided email address.",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: Colors.black87,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  reUseTextField("Enter email address", Icons.email_outlined,
                      false, _emailTextController),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  ForgotPassworSubmitdButton(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container ForgotPassworSubmitdButton() {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
      height: 50,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
      ),
      child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            passwordReset();
          },
          style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                  return Colors.black26;
                }
                return Colors.white;
              }),
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
              )),
          child: const Text(
            "Submit",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black87,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 16,
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey man, I had same error, all e-mails were on span box.

Comment: I got the same error, too. :-(